# Remove element from observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I'm stuck on "working with lists and collections", and need help finding the error. The delete button is not working.

You can check my souce on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/syntaxerror00100/pen/bprbOx).

```
    code
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] *in the question itself* (instead of posting fake code to get around the built in warning) so that (for one thing) link rot cannot render the question useless to future visitors. In addition, be specific about the error you're getting and the things you've tried and debugged yourself.

Comment: simple mate try `.bind(this)` at remove function end it will work . `this` refers to current context . here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZvopb

Answer (score 1):

Keeping track of exactly what `this` is can be difficult. It is a good idea to use variables when you can, and `this` only when you really need to. Think of `this` as indicating that the code should be re-usable with different supplied contexts. It's important if you're using prototypes, for example. (Also be aware that the context supplied by a binding is not always obvious.)

One common technique is to create a variable `self` in a constructor that you immediately assign to `this`, and then use it. That ensures that no matter what the context, the function calls operate as intended.

The [revealing pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/) is another way to minimize your `this` exposure.

```js
// KO WITH OBSERVABLEARRAY

function mMember(name, gender) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = ko.observable(gender);
}

function vmMember() {
  var self = this;

  self.MemberGender = [{
    gen: 'Male',
    tag: 'M'
  }, {
    gen: 'Female',
    tag: 'F'
  }];


  self.members = ko.observableArray([
    new mMember('Mark', this.MemberGender[0]),
    new mMember('Lester', this.MemberGender[0])
  ]);


  self.add = function() {
    self.members.push(new mMember('', this.MemberGender[0]));
  };


  self.remove = function(member) {
    self.members.remove(member);
  }

}


ko.applyBindings(new vmMember());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- OBSERVABLE ARRAY HERE -->

<button data-bind='click:add'>Add</button>

<table>

  <th>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td>Initial</td>
    </tr>
  </th>

  <tbody data-bind='foreach:members'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input data-bind='value:name' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select data-bind="options: $root.MemberGender, value: gender,optionsText: 'gen'"></select>
      </td>
      <td data-bind='text:gender().tag'></td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind='click:$root.remove'>x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```